# PhoneAuthProvider.credential() returning AuthCredential instead of PhoneAuthCredential

Tags: flutter, dart, firebase-authentication

`firebase_auth: ^0.18.1+2`

`import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';`

`await PhoneAuthProvider.credential()` is returning a value of type `AuthCredential` instead of type `PhoneAuthCredential` as specified in the FlutterFire docs (https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/auth/phone/)

What am I doing wrong?